# Adding an interceptor to a GRPC call in Angular

Tags: angular, grpc, interceptor

I have a GRPC call being performed from an npm package which I can see from the back is using `@ngx-grpc`. Now I want to intercept the GRPC to perform an extra operation(I want to add a header,but it does not matter what I do) while GRPC call is being performed.
I have created class for that as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GrpcEvent, GrpcMessage, GrpcRequest } from '@ngx-grpc/common';
import { GrpcHandler, GrpcInterceptor,  } from '@ngx-grpc/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GrpcInterceptorHandler implements GrpcInterceptor {

  intercept<Q extends GrpcMessage, S extends GrpcMessage>(request: GrpcRequest<Q, S>, next: GrpcHandler): Observable<GrpcEvent<S>> {
    // Modify the request metadata here
    request.requestMetadata.set('custom-header', 'value');

    // Log the request and metadata for debugging purposes
    console.log('gRPC request:', request);
    console.log('gRPC metadata:', request.requestMetadata);

    // Forward the request to the next handler in the chain
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

and added that in the `providers` of the `app.module.ts`:

```
{
      provide: GRPC_INSTANT_GRPC_CLIENT_SETTINGS,
      useClass: GrpcInterceptorHandler,
      multi: true,
      useValue: {
        host: environment.gatewayUrl,
        path: ""
      } as GrpcWebClientSettings,
    },
```

But I cannot see the interceptor being called. What I am missing in here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your GrpcInterceptorHandler as GRPC_INTERCEPTORS in the providers in app.module.ts file

```
{
  provide : GRPC_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass : GrpcInterceptorHandler 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are providing a `ClassProvider` & `ValueProvider` in one `Provider`. I.e. you specify the `useClass` & `useValue` in the same object.

Instead you should provide your `Interceptor` & potential custom `Settings` in two separate `Provider` objects:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: GRPC_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: GrpcInterceptorHandler,
    multi: true,
  },
  {
    provide: GRPC_INSTANT_GRPC_CLIENT_SETTINGS,
    useValue: {
      host: environment.gatewayUrl,
      path: ''
    } as GrpcWebClientSettings
  }
]
```

⚠️ Attention: it doesn't look like that your `Interceptor` injects itself any custom settings (e.g. via `@Inject(GRPC_INSTANT_GRPC_CLIENT_SETTINGS) settings: GrpcWebClientSettings`).
Therefore, you would not need to provide a value for that. I.e. second `Provider` would not be required in that case.

ℹ️ Another option is to do it similar to how the library implemented its own
[GrpcLoggerInterceptor](https://github.com/ngx-grpc/ngx-grpc/blob/master/packages/core/src/lib/grpc-logger-interceptor.ts) and [GrpcLoggerModule](https://github.com/ngx-grpc/ngx-grpc/blob/master/packages/core/src/lib/grpc-logger.module.ts) which provides a `forRoot()` method.